# How to pick the best support for your ADC?

Tags: league-of-legends

Since I have babbled a wall of text I will start with my question, **Should a support champ be picked to cover an ADCs weaknesses or strengths?** Some examples would do just nicely, I have seen a chart that gives the best combos for support/ADC, couldn't find it myself.

What I'm trying to do with this question is provide a sort of foundation for picking my support champion for an ADC champion or even vice versa what ADC should I go with certain support champions. I ask this because of the key role support plays, as games are won and lost in the hands of a support just as easily as they are with any role in LoL.

Support plays such a big role early game for Bot Lane that overlooking the importance will cause you too fail repeatedly. I do my best to pick support champions (I prefer meta support champions) that I have done well with in a certain ADC/Support combo. I will mention one of my favorite combinations being Leona and Twitch. Twitch usually being a weaker ADC (atleast in my eyes) combined with the awsome power that is Leona allows me to feed him repeatedly, and not until yesterday did I find myself doubting my knowledge of the support roll. Lets just say I did awful, one of my worst games with Leona, the weird part being the mistakes I made weren't all that severe, mistakes like harassing to hard, causing us to lose the trade and be forced to tower hug till a jungler saves us. We basically just got outplayed and for some reason those are the hardest loses to swallow.

Anyways, I started to think "why am I playing this support champion just because I have done well with this support/adc combo in the past". I started to do this a lot when playing League of Legends as I had recently watched a video about elo hell where the guy talked about the only thing that holds players back is their refusal to take blame for their own mistakes in a game and blame everything else. Having been consistanly stuck around 1000 elo last season with over 100 games played in ranked, I had lost all hope of ever getting anywhere close to 1250 or 1500 for that matter.

Getting back on track now, I go back to my thought about support/ADC combos. I realized that I need to start picking support champions to play to an ADCs weakness and/or strength. An example I will mention is the Vayne/Nunu, which to me is probably the deadliest bot lane combination. Nunu having huge sustain and harass abilities allows vayne to lay back and CS all day and if engaged in a 2v2, Nunu gives an attack speed boost that makes Vayne tear through even the tankiest of supports. Not to mention Vayne being the strongest late game ADC in LoL, some people would debate Corki being the best late game (semantics really).

Now to get to my question, I would like to start picking support champions that mesh well with an ADC. Support Champs that cover an ADCs weakness or plays to their strengths, or both. I think counterpicks bot lane to be a mere myth and really never decides the outcome of the game. I'm convinced ADC/Support combinations to be the real path to winning.

Comment: More important than the actual champion pair, if you're going to be solo queue, is how well you master your own champion, and how you communicate with your carry to make sure you don't play aggressive when he wants to camp under the tower. I'm spending most of my time as a support, and I really observe that. It's almost always a matter of positioning and timing, more than the actual combination. That said, of course there are champions which are synergizing better than others.

Comment: @Gnoupi recently I have taken to watching Aphromoo (A LoL Pro, known for playing support) he basically says an aggresive support is the best way to win the lane. By interupting the enemy ADC CS by harassing and allowing your ADC to CS unopposed. Obviously that requires a certain amount of skill so as not to get poked.

Comment: not saying the opposite. Riot are even hinting in this direction in the Season 3, with the pickpocket trait in utility. They actively reward you for poking and playing aggressive. But again it's more about how you play, more than the actual combination.

Comment: It doesn't matter how good I am, for ex. an alistar/Vayne combination, by the time I am done being CCd by their combined stuns and knockups/knockbacks I am dead. But if say i was leona, i could stun the vayne long enough for w.e adc to be unstunned and be able to either escape or return enough dmg to make it even. I am aware that skill has a lot to do with it but in the end the varying factor is counters and team composition. @Gnoupi

Comment: I agree with @Gnoupi it really depends on your adc in solo queue. You should play to how they play if they're less aggressive, you can't be aggressive or you'll just get caught out and die. In solo queue first goal of support is to mesh with your adc's playstyle :)

Comment: @Brian A passive ADC is a bad ADC in my opinion, if you aren't poking then you aren't CSing, iF you aren't CSing your losing.

Comment: Not to further bring discussion to comments, but poking is not synonymous with cs. So your statement of if you're not poking you're not csing is false. Poking pushes their team back to allow you easier access to creep but if you focus too much on poking you're not getting cs. The adc should focus on farm over poke and support should be focused on poke while keeping in range of the adc.

Comment: @Brian you basically just agreed with me and disagree with me at the same time haha. If you can't poke and CS at the same time ADC isn't for you. Or your champ isn't built for it, in that case just let your support handle it.

Comment: lol blows me away how I still manage to get downvotes with this question, yet have 5 favs

Comment: @Paralytic see the 2nd question(what questions should I not ask here) of FAQ http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq .  It is debatable as to whether this question has answer, and it is definitely producing a ton of opinions and discussion.

Comment: @Brian well like you said what is considered subjective, is in fact subjective itself. Typically questions that ask about strategies aren't downvoted is why i commented.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends, I like to choose a support based on the ADC early game play, if the ADC is squishy, let's say for example `Ezreal`, I'm more likely to pick `Soraka` or `Sona` to sustain him on lane. But, if you have a more sustainable ADC, you can pick a more aggressive support like `Leona`, `Nunu` or `Zyra`.

Another thing to observe is the synergy of Support/ADC level, `Leona` has her [Q,W and E](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Leona/Ability_Details) ready by level 3, which can combo really good with `Graves`, where in this level he's really great. We could also mention some good combos like `Ashe` and `Janna`, due to the synergy of Janna's Shield and Ashe's crit, and Ashe's slow with Janna's slow.

Besides, picking a champion that you enjoy playing, which will also help in your performance, you could ask the ADC which support he enjoys to play with, if he has any preference and you feel his preference is useful, you could pick it too.

I found the [League Support Suggester](http://nebupookins.github.com/LeagueSupportSuggester/), a recommendation software to provide the best support for your current needs.

I've also found the following chart which really helps me when to choose a good support for my ADC, I usually pick one of the three recommended:

[image]

Comment: the exact chart i saw so glad you found it!

Comment: to mention your examples, maybe thats part of my problem when picking support. I usually go tanky supports with squishy ADC.

Comment: It's an interesting chart, but it feels a bit artificial, in my opinion. It's more important to pick a support champ you know perfectly than picking one from the "matching chart".

Comment: It's not artificial it's obviously based on stats of some sort. But you have to take stats with a pinch of salt because they always refer to others, not you. So if you think after 1k+ wins that you have mastered every champion equally then you could follow this chart to the letter. :)

Comment: @Gnoupi your comment applies to Paralytic's comment. If he says he prefer to play with tanky supports, maybe he could play better with them. But, personally, in my case, I often play support, and I know how to play with everyone, so maybe, it's a good idea to follow the chart.
I'll also append this to the answer.

Comment: I'm able to pick up any champion and do well, just the other day I didn't realize I was in the lobby for picking champions and random rolled a kog'maw having never played kogmaw before (as he is free this week) and had to play jungle being the only role left. not to mention with flash/exhaust and support runes. my team won the game in short. definitly chalking that up to be a once in a lifetime event too.

Comment: EDIT: Added http://nebupookins.github.com/LeagueSupportSuggester/

Comment: In [the originating reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/12r48y/picking_guide_for_solo_q_supports/), spellsy also links to a [spreadsheet containing more details](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AllLJAxUt7qcdGxZeWM2bzZDZUh6djV3NDVrM0tGS1E&output=html) on his reasonings for each of the matchups.

Comment: @Yves - thanks for the full link. It does feel a bit subjective, when reading the excel file behind the infographic. There are some good points, but in my opinion it's too reductive to organize it like this, with only 3 choices.

Comment: @Gnoupi I agree completely; it's still important to note that this is just one person's opinion -- even if they _do_ play professionally. It's still a good starting point though.

Answer (score 8):

First of all (before my opinion) I have a chart that might be what u were looking for:

http://www.lolking.net/charts?region=all&league=ranked&type=bottom-lane-synergy&range=monthly

You can see there (stats talking) which combos are most successful in bot lane.

Other than that my opinion is that a good support will be able to FACILITATE the adc carry the best possible way.

That being said you have to get to know your carry first. What is his/her most comfortable playstyle while laning?

Is he `aggressive or defensive`? Does he focus on `farming or poking`?
If you're solo queue and you don't know the other guy just ask him that exact thing before the game starts.

It makes sense that if you play with an aggressive (high risk-high reward) carry you want to get a support that boosts his strengths (i.e. His offensive stats). 
If you play with a carry that prefers to farm a lot and be defensive you have to help him out with a support that boosts his defensive or utility stats and can heal him.

Another aspect is WHO your carry picks. You have to have good synergy. I'm not going into specific details as you already have the chart. Just giving you food for thought.

It's important to think it out on your own. Because there are no rules set in stone. Trial and Error with a specific teammate will make you a better support and a better champion picker.

EDIT: Decided to give a couple of my favorite support champs when I play adc (usually my pref. roles are ADC>Solo Top>Support>Mid>Jungle (ewww - lol) so you get to hear the carry's side of the story)

Being Ezreal very often I find that a very fun combo is Lux + Ez. Having similar ults that can kill any squishy instantly if synced well plus really good poking ability.
That all changes though if u have a strong healer on the other side.

One of my favorites is Alistar with Ez. Alistar is a true bodyguard which is just what ez needs actually. He can heal you and can be a pain in the ass for anyone trying to get close to you. Plus his stun is very helpful if you decide to attack because it keeps them still for long enough for you to hit them with a full round of your spells.

Other fun combos are Nunu + Miss Fortune, Nunu + Ashe (although ashe is really weak these days I don't pick her anymore).

Comment: I usually Solo qeue ranked, being that none of my friends can't ever be serious they just like to troll. Still fun but ranked is when I get serious. So getting to know an ADC doesn't usually happen.

Comment: @Paralytic In solo/duo queue, it's best to duo if you're planning on going bot and leave the other 3 spots for the soloers. But i know the feeling you describe :) And I realize you can't always NOT play the best lane in the game just because you 're solo hehe
I will update my answer with my personal favorites! :)

Comment: Actually, the link shows mostly the most popular picks, rather than the most successful. At least it's presented in such way. But the results are obviously biased for less popular/more difficult support champions.

Comment: @Gnoupi if you hover over each dot you will see that it has a percentage of Wins. The Size of the dots shows the number of games played. So it actually shows BOTH popularity and Success.
Plus this chart is NOT subjective. It comes from LoLking which accesses the stats of LoL Database. So it's real Stats talking.
I can't say the same for the chart given by Eduardo (which I think is pretty nice - don't get me wrong)

Comment: really nunu is the best support champ in my opinion haha. And Ez is such a beast, I stopped playing him as games were just to easy.

Comment: @Paralytic Did my first penta with Ez (snif snif)

Comment: with over 400 combined wins between ranked and normal I have never had a Penta, Graves is the only one i've come close with. I think i've had one close penta with ez, just don't remember.

Comment: @PanagiotisPalladinos - yes, I see that there is this, however the chart is organized more according to popularity than actual win-rate, that was my point. When I say biased, I meant rather "not significant" (statistically speaking), in fact, given the lower number of matches. For example, trying to judge on the compatibility of Karma with the different ADCs is complicated, given the very low number of matches.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it is more important to cover the weaknesses of your **team-mate** rather than the weaknesses of his champion. Why so? There are mistakes he will always do, whichever carry he picks.

This obviously means you have to know who you are laning with and the reason why people often playing together will won the lane over two "match-made" enemies.

Of course, there is always many ways to cover for one player weaknesses. But you need to know ALL the supports you can play. If you can pick champion which have a synergy and allow you to correctly support your team-mate, good for you. But you should always give the preference to a champion that helps your player rather than one which helps his carry.

However, what to do with someone you don't know. Well, learn fast. Pick a champion you truly master and do your best. Does he follow when you go forward? Does he reacts when you put a stun? Does he do well when you get caught? All these situation will help you see how he his playing. Then adapt your behaviour to this.

Comment: I think also part of the problem is that a lot of ADCs have little to no experience with support champs, and vice versa. For me if Im paired with a champ with high cc ill make sure im not far from him. If its a sustain champ i just let them do their thing and worry about my cs. For example, when i see a taric start making a move to stun i'll be quick to follow.

Answer (score -1):

Well here is a simple answer don't hate if its already said I don't say it like this to offend but to just get to the point if your having trouble picking a support just as the AFDC what support they would like

Comment: That is one way to go about it, but just because they like a certain support doesn't mean it's the best choice.

Comment: This answer doesn't provide anything over the already accepted one.